# HTML Background repeat been cut off after scroll

Tags: html, css

Im trying to make a menu, its working well however, when i make the window smaller and scroll across, the background doesn't extend. Example:

[image: Full screen view]
[image]

The first image is in full screen and second image is after i have scrolled across the page. As you can see the background does not extend. Below is my CSS:

```
body{
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
background-color: #717070;
 }
.header{
background-image: url("img/bgsmall.png");
height: 100px;
background-repeat: repeat-x;
min-width: 1000px;

}
.logo{
margin-left:320px;
float:left;
 }
#menu{
position: relative;
height: 100px;
text-align: center;
width:auto;
margin-left:600px;
min-width:1000px;
}
#menu ul{
list-style: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
position:relative;
}
#menu li{
float: left;
display: inline;
padding-top:35px;
position:relative;
text-transform:uppercase;
}

#menu li a{
text-decoration: none;
padding-left: 32px;
padding-right: 32px;
font-size: 15px;
font-family: arial;
color: #ffffff;
text-align:center;
}
#menu li a:visited{
color: #ffffff;
}
#menu li a:hover{
color: #D86C00;
}
```

HTML CODE

```
  <html>
  <head>

  <link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
 <body>
  <div class="header">

<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">page1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">page2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">page3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">page4</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div></div>





 </body>
 </html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add `position:absolute;` to your `.header` class.

Answer (score 0):

It's your min-width:1000px; on the #menu that is causing this.  Without knowing what layout it is that you want to achieve it's hard to say what you should do to replace this, but taking that out sorts out that particular issue

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this problem by two way:

1-

```
body{
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
background-image: url("img/bgsmall.png");
background-repeat: repeat-x;
background-color: #717070;
 }
.header{
height: 100px;
}
```

2-

Remove "min-width: 1000px;" from header style